# How to get row content in excel/csv file with python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv, openpyxl

I have an excel file with rankings that looks like this (snippet):

[image: Excel Screenshot]

I want to get those values in the first column by inputting the value from the second column. For example if I input Roger Federer I should get 0.

I have this so far:

```
name_list = ["Roger Federer", "Rafael Nadal", "Novak Djokovic]

df = pd.DataFrame(name_list)
df.to_excel("B14.xlsx")
print(df.loc["Roger Federer"])
```

and it returns KeyError: 'Roger Federer' when I was expecting to get: 0

Comment: `print(df.loc[df[0].eq('Roger Federer'), 0].index)`